# Why can´t I build the same app which I had built before with MIT App Inventor?

Tags: app-inventor

I had designed and built an App using MIT App Inventor 9 months ago. Now, I was trying to build the same App again to download the apk file but I receive this error. I have really no idea about it. I hope you help me fix it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

your error message is DX execution failed
@Boban would say, "you have too much of something"...

here is @SteveJG’s monster list of things to check https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mitappinventortest/fLiMEfPh09Q/1Ia0AaQEXogJ

each point on the monster list might be the issue, why someone gets a DX execution failed error… that thread is a collection of several possibilities, which have been collected by @SteveJG during the years while answering questions like that… hope that helps… if not, please ask in the MIT App Inventor community...
https://community.appinventor.mit.edu/t/i-have-this-message-dx-execution-failed/11682/2